# Running out of memory when deploying an extremely simple Flask app in Heroku

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, heroku, fast-ai

I want to deploy a simple machine learning model (resnet34) made with Fast AI to Heroku.

My whole flask app is a single file:

```
from flask import Flask
from fastai.vision.all import *

app = Flask(__name__)

learn = load_learner("./export.pkl")

@app.route("/<path:image_url>")
def hello_world(image_url):
    print(image_url)
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    img = PILImage.create(response.content)
    predictions = learn.predict(img)
    print(predictions)
    return predictions[0]
```

**It works fine a couple of times,** but heroku then starts logging things like:
[image: image image 691×44 18.9 KB]

I don't understand why this is happening... my intuition tells me that the garbage collector should be fine here.

Here are my requirements.txt

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

torch==1.8.1+cpu
torchvision==0.9.1+cpu
fastai>=2.3.1
Flask==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0

Pillow

requests==2.26.0
```

EDIT: The answer I posted myself is not completely right. The root cause was that I wasn't closing the images:
correct code:

```
@app.route("/<path:image_url>")
def hello_world(image_url):
    print(image_url)
    response = requests.get(image_url)
    img = PILImage.create(response.content)
    predictions = learn.predict(img)
    img.close()
    return predictions[0]
```

Comment: can you edit your question and add the requirements.txt

Comment: Hi @charchit I've added them :)

Comment: sorry but I don't understand why your slug size is too large. even after using cpu version. Maybe it's fastai which is making size larger.  maybe this hepls https://course.fast.ai/deployment_heroku

Comment: Hi @charchit, my slug size is not too large. I am able to deploy the app and it works fine for a couple of predictions. What happens is that it seems that after doing X amount of predictions the memory isn't being collected so heroku starts logging the logs I've shown above

Comment: I don't know machine learning. But I think you are storing data in pkl file. which gets too large after X number of predictions? am I right?

Comment: Not really. The pkl file contains just the parameters of the model I'm using. Doesn't store the predictions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235107/discussion-between-charchit-and-michael).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was that the **pycache** was getting bigger and bigger.

Be sure to run your app with the following env var set:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```